# How to prevent auto re-route on off route in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I was trying to prevent the MapboxNavigation from automatically finding a new route, when the user is detected as off-route, since I would like to perform another action instead.

I used the OffRouteObserver to perform this action and it is running, but it seems that the Re-route is still executed.

In the MapboxNavigation.kt file, there is an internal off route observer which calls reroute() function when off route is detected. I have no idea how to change this.

If this feature is possible, please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few options that you can do:

1. Override the default reroute controller, see `MapboxNavigation.setRerouteController`;
2. You can wait for new routes on re-route (see `MapboxNavigation.registerRoutesObserver`) and check if they were fetched from OnBoard tiles, then do what you want to do with it. To check where routes were fetched from, you need to invoke [NavigationRoute.origin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/e4c87ee340903c63159afb1a601e9ba29de5f973/libnavigation-base/src/main/java/com/mapbox/navigation/base/route/NavigationRoute.kt#L238);
3. If both above options are not working, please open a feature request in [mapbox-android-navigation repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues);